# Product catalog

Tags: code-golf, string

This problem is about separating a string representing a product identifier into three components.

- The first part consists of upper and lower letters of arbitrary length which represents the warehouse.
- The second part is digits which represents the product number. This part is also of arbitrary length.
- The last part is qualifiers as size and colours, and this part continues to the end of the string. The qualifiers are guaranteed to start with a capital letter and consist of alphanumeric characters.

Each part should be printed clearly separated. It is guaranteed that each part is non-empty.

The winner is the one who uses least bytes to solve this problem.

**Example:**

*Input:* UK7898S14


*Output:*
UK
7898
S14

Here UK is United Kingdom, 7898 is the product code, and S14 is size 14.

**Example 2:**
*Input:* cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD


*Output:*
cphDK
1234
CYELLOWS14QGOOD

Here cphDK is Copenhagen, Denmark, 1234 is the product code, CYELLOWS14QGOOD represents yellow colour, size 14, and good quality.

Comment: Is each part non-empty?

Comment: @KarlNapf Yes. Each part is non-empty.

Comment: @Emigna An addition example has now been included.

Comment: “The first part consists of upper and lower letters” – Maybe one of the examples could contain such mixture of upper and lowercase letters. And maybe also a country code that is not 2 characters long. Also, could the qualifier contain non-alphanumeric characters, like “Quality★★★☆☆”?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I hope you're not going to use this in production.

Comment: I won't. The story about the products was just to make the puzzle more fun. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

### Perl, 12 bytes

11 bytes of code + 1 byte for `-p` flag.

```pl
s/\d+/
$&
/
```

To run it :

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/
$&
/' <<< "CYELLOWS14QGOOD"
```

Comment: Love the simplicity! :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>28</s> <s>14</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to *Dom Hastings*.
Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Martin Ender*.

```
S1`(\d+)
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=UzFgKFxkKyk&input=Y3BoREsxMjM0Q1lFTExPV1MxNFFHT09E)

Comment: Using the same mechanism as @Dada's answer, you can save another 4 bytes: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MWBcZCsKwrYkJsK2&input=Y3BoREsxMjM0Q1lFTExPV1MxNFFHT09E (tbh, probably even more, but that's all _I_ could save! :))

Comment: @DomHastings. Aah, nice idea going with the replace!

Answer (score 4):

### APL, 18

```
{⍵⊂⍨3⌊+\1,2≠/⍵∊⎕D}'UK7898S14'
UK  7898  S14
```

Works by searching the first 2 points where there is a change from character to digit or vice-versa, and using those to split the string.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```js
s=>/(\D+)(\d+)(.+)/.exec(s).slice(1)
```

#### Example

```js
const f =

s=>/(\D+)(\d+)(.+)/.exec(s).slice(1)

console.log(f("UK7898S14"));
console.log(f("cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD"));
```

Comment: @Arnauld Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 36 bytes (no regex)

```
d c='/'<c&&c<':'
(span d<$>).break d
```

This gives the result in the format `("UK",("7898","S14"))`.
The idea is to split at the first digit, and then split the rest at the first non-digit.
[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/liXE8z).

Comment: Nice use of fmap on a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/\d+/,`
$&
`)
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Grax

#### Examples

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/\d+/,`
$&
`)

console.log(f('UK7898S14'));
console.log(f('cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD'));
```

Comment: You can reduce 2 more characters by using $& in your replace and removing the parentheses.  `s=>s.replace(/\d+/,\`
$&
\`)`

Answer (score 2):

## Gema, <s>17</s> 12 characters

(The trick of not handling the country code explicitly shamelessly borrowed from [Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada)'s [Perl solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98950). Appreciation should be expressed there.)

```
<D>*=\n$1\n*
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<D>*=\n$1\n*' <<< 'UK7898S14'
UK
7898
S14

bash-4.3$ gema '<D>*=\n$1\n*' <<< 'cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD'
cphDK
1234
CYELLOWS14QGOOD
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>39</del> <del>37</del> 16 bytes

Saved a lot of bytes thanks to Emigna.

It uses CP-1252 encoding.

```
TvDSdykF¬?¦}¶?}?

T                push "10"
 v               for each element (i.e., 1 and 0). Element is stored in 'y'
  DS             split string (input during the first iteration)
    d            for each character, 1 if digit or 0 otherwise
     yk          get index of the first occurrence of 'y'
       F         for 0 <= i < string.firstIndexOf(y)
        ¬?       print the first character of the string
          ¦      remove it from the string
           }     end inner for
            ¶?   display a newline
              }  end outer for
               ? display the remaining string
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VHZEU2R5a0bCrD_Cpn3Ctj99Pw&input=Y3BoREsxMjM0Q1lFTExPV1MxNFFHT09E)

(This is my first post here!)

Comment: You can save at least 14 bytes by [checking digits instead of letters](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RFNkMWtGwqw_wqZ9wrY_RFNkMGtGwqw_wqZ9wrY_Pw&input=Y3BoREsxMjM0Q1lFTExPV1MxNFFHT09E). And this can likely be golfed more.

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG :)

Comment: Thanks! And you are right, actually I went all naive on this one, literally from left to right. I also tried to dig `.páà¬` to get the first part, but it doesn't seem to help for the rest at first glance.

Comment: Feel free to update your answer with my code (and golf it some more if you can). I don't feel that it's different enough to warrant it's own answer.

Comment: Ok I'll do it then as I found a way to put it in a loop. Nothing too sophisticated, but at least it goes down to 16 bytes. Thank you again!
(Now I have to update the explanations... but there are fewer bytes to explain)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 40 Bytes

I don't know much Regex, but thankfully this problem is simple enough :) Seperates the input string into a list of length 3 which contains each part.

```python
import re
lambda k:re.split('(\d+)',k,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, <s>81</s> 73 bytes

```
function y=f(x)
[~,~,~,m,~,~,s]=regexp(x,'(?<=^\D+)\d+');y=[s(1) m s(2)];
```

Function that accepts a string and returns a cell array of three strings. Tested in version R20105b.

Example use:

```
>> f('UK7898S14')
ans = 
    'UK'    '7898'    'S14'

>> f('cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD')
ans = 
    'cphDK'    '1234'    'CYELLOWS14QGOOD'
```

#### Explanation

The regular expression `(?<=^\D+)\d+')` matches a group of digits preceded by non-digits from the start of the string; the latter are not part of the match.

The fourth output of [`regexp`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) is the `'match'`; and the seventh output is the `'split'`, that is, the two parts of the string before and after the match.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>200</s> <s>185</s> <s>174</s> 167 bytes

```
import java.util.regex.*;String c(String s){Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)").matcher(s);s="";for(int i=0;i<3;)if(m.matches())s+=m.group(++i)+" ";return s;}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/z6inUN)

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class M{
  static String c(String s){
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)").matcher(s);
    s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3;){
      if(m.matches()){
        s += m.group(++i) + " ";
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("UK7898S14"));
    System.out.println(c("cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
UK 7898 S14 
cphDK 1234 CYELLOWS14QGOOD
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

```js
s=>/(.+?)(\d+)(.*)/.exec(s).slice(1)
```

#### Examples

```js
let f =

s=>/(.+?)(\d+)(.*)/.exec(s).slice(1)

console.log(f('UK7898S14'));
console.log(f('cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD'));
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>191</s> 177 bytes

Golfed:

```
void F(string s){var a=s.ToList();int i=a.FindIndex(char.IsDigit);int n=a.FindIndex(i,char.IsUpper);Console.Write($"{s.Substring(0,i)}\n{s.Substring(i,n-i)}\n{s.Substring(n)}");
```

Ungolfed:

```
    void F(string s)
    {
        var a = s.ToList();
        int i = a.FindIndex(char.IsDigit);
        int n = a.FindIndex(i, char.IsUpper);

        Console.Write($"{s.Substring(0, i)}\n{s.Substring(i, n - i)}\n{s.Substring(n)}");
    }
```

EDIT1: @Link Ng saved 14 bytes.

Comment: You don't need ToCharArray(). string is already IEnumerable<char>

Comment: Of course, I can't believe I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 48 bytes

```
print_r(preg_split('/(\D+|\d+)\K/',$argv[1],3));
```

With its `$limit` parameter, and the fantastically useful `\K`, `preg_split()` is perfect for this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 28 bytes

```
->s{puts s.sub(/\d+/,"\n\\&\n")}
```

This surrounds the first cluster of digits with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <strike>61 59 56</strike>55 bytes

```
preg_match('/(\D+)(\d+)(.+)/',$argv[1],$a);print_r($a);
```

This does output the initial code as well:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD
    [1] => cphDK
    [2] => 1234
    [3] => CYELLOWS14QGOOD
)
```

#### Edit

Thanks to @manatwork for saving a few bytes for me
Thanks to @RomanGräf for another few bytes saved

Comment: `[\d]`? :o `\d` is enough.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks.  I don't use regex enough (arguably a good thing) and started down the [0-9]+ route before remembering about \d

Comment: Why not replace `[a-z]` with `\D`?

Comment: Now that you have no `[a-z]`, the `i` flag is not needed either.

Comment: I really need to pend more time working on regular expressions.

Comment: You can save  a byte by switching to the deprecated (and removed in php 7) `eregi()`. It would be much more but the `ereg()` functions don't seem to support `\d` or `\D`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript without regex, <strike>84</strike> <strike>81</strike> 79 bytes

`p=>{for(i=n=o='';i<p.length;){if(n==isNaN(c=p[i++])){o+=' ';n++}o+=c}return o}`

Comment: You could put all initializations in a single place: `o=n=i=''`.

Comment: And move the assignment to c to its first usage: `isNaN(c=p[i++])`.

Comment: `p=>{for(i=n=o=0;i<p.length;){c=p[i++];if(n++==c<59){o+=' '}o+=c}return o}`

Comment: @RomanGräf, the initialization should remain `''` because the o, to which the result will be concatenated. But sadly your code is not working for me, n needs to be incremented conditionally.

Comment: `p=>{for(i=n=0,o='';i<p.length;){c=p[i++];if(n==c<59){o+=' ';n++}o+=c}return o}`

Comment: Sorry, but definitely something more should be modified as the condition you suggested is not equivalent with the old one: `isNaN('A')` true vs. `'A'<59` false, and similarly `isNaN('1')` false vs. `'1'<59` true.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the solution. I left the init of `o` where it was as we need it to be initialized with `''`, and we really don't gain anything by moving it around. Out of curiosity, how does `<59` work?

Comment: ok, moved the initializations around. I had no idea we could start with `''` and increment...

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 47 characters

(43 characters code + 4 characters command line options.)

```
match("(\\D+)(\\d+)(.+)").captures[].string
```

(Again the old story: fairly elegant at the beginning, then becomes painfully verbose.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -Rr 'match("(\\D+)(\\d+)(.+)").captures[].string' <<< 'UK7898S14'
UK
7898
S14

bash-4.3$ jq -Rr 'match("(\\D+)(\\d+)(.+)").captures[].string' <<< 'cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD'
cphDK
1234
CYELLOWS14QGOOD
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=match%28%22%28%5C%5CD%2b%29%28%5C%5Cd%2b%29%28.%2b%29%22%29.captures[].string&j=%22cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD%22) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

## R, <strike>63</strike> 52 bytes

Edit: Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to @JDL

Takes input from stdin and prints to stdout:

```
gsub("([a-z]+)(\\d+)(.+)","\\1 \\2 \\3",scan(,""),T)
```

Example output:

```
[1] "UK 7898 S1"
[1] "cphDK 1234 CYELLOWS14QGOOD"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `gsub (...,"\\1 \\2 \\3")` be more efficient?

Comment: @JDL Not sure I follow. Care to elaborate or give an example?

Comment: something like `gsub("([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)(.+)","\\1 \\2 \\3",scan())`, though the first argument can probably be expressed as something smaller than that...

Comment: @JDL Very clever but I have no idea  how the `"\\1 \\2 \\3"` replacement works though.  Also updated the regex pattern a bit and use `ignore.case = TRUE`.

Comment: They just mean "output whatever was captured in the first/second/third pair of `()` brackets.

Comment: @JDL Alright, that's very useful to know,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>103</s> <s>94</s> 88 bytes

Solution without using regex

```py
a,b=input(),""
for f in a:
 if ord(f)<58:b+=f
 elif b"":c,d=a.split(b);print c,b,d;break
```

Simply extracts the numbers from the middle then slices the input using the number as an index. Requires quotes around the input but I didn't see anywhere that quotes are disallowed.

-9 by splitting a on the middle number then print the components with b in the middle

-6 Thanks to @Shebang

Test Cases

```
D:\>python codes.py
"UK7898S14"
UK 7898 S14

D:\>python codes.py
"cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD"
cphDK 1234 CYELLOWS14QGOOD
```

Comment: `b!="" -> b>""` and `c=a.split(b) -> c,d=a.split(b) ... print c[0],b,c[1] -> print c,b,d` saves 5 bytes.

Comment: Very nice hints @Shebang. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I forgot empty strings are falsy. You can save another 3 bytes by just making it `elif b:` ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 39 bytes

```
StringSplit[#,a:DigitCharacter..:>a,2]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string as input, and returns a list of strings as output.

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 274 bytes

```
(let((g 0)(j'())(k'())(l'())(m list->string)(r reverse)(n char-numeric?)(c cons))(for((i(string->list s)))
(when(and(= g 0)(n i))(set! g 1))(when(and(= g 1)(not(n i)))(set! g 2))(match g[0(set! j(c i j))]
[1(set! k(c i k))][2(set! l(c i l))]))(list(m(r j))(m(r k))(m(r l))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (let ((g 0)
        (j '())
        (k '())
        (l '())
        (m list->string)
        (r reverse)
        (n char-numeric?)
        (c cons))
    (for ((i (string->list s)))
      (when (and (= g 0) (n i)) (set! g 1)  )
      (when (and (= g 1) (not (n i))) (set! g 2) )
      (match g
        [0 (set! j (c i j))]
        [1 (set! k (c i k))]
        [2 (set! l (c i l))]))
    (list (m (r j)) (m (r k)) (m (r l)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "UK7898S14")
(f "cphDK1234CYELLOWS14QGOOD")
```

Output:

```
'("UK" "7898" "S14")
'("cphDK" "1234" "CYELLOWS14QGOOD")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O<65ITḣ2‘ṬœṗµY
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Tzw2NUlU4bijMuKAmOG5rMWT4bmXwrVZ&input=&args=IlVLNzg5OFMxNCI)**

#### How?

```
O<65ITḣ2‘ṬœṗµY - Main link: productIdentifier   e.g. "UK7898S14"
O              - cast to ordinals               e.g. [85,75,55,56,57,56,83,49,52]
 <65           - less than 65?                  e.g. [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
    I          - incremental difference         e.g. [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0]
     T         - truthy indexes                 e.g. [2, 6, 7]
      ḣ2       - head to 2                      e.g. [2, 6]
        ‘      - increment                      e.g. [3, 7]
         Ṭ     - set truthy indexes             e.g. [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
          œṗ   - split y at truthy indexes of x e.g. ["UK", "7898", "S14"]
            µ  - monadic chain separation
             Y - join with line feeds
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 107 bytes

```
#define p(x) printf("%c",x);
f(char*s){for(;*s>64;s++)p(*s)p(10)for(;*s<58;s++)p(*s)p(10)for(;*s;s++)p(*s)}
```

Call with:

```
int main()
{
   f("UK7898S14");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 74 bytes

```
v=>new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\d+").Replace(v,"\n$&\n",1);
```

Replace 1st set of digits with carriage return, set of digits, and another carriage return, as Johan Karlsson did for JavaScript.